# What is the difference between red5 RC1 and RC2?

Tags: broadcast

What is the difference between the red5 versions RC1 and RC2 ?

and what does RC mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC mean Release candidate, it means your release could be released as production version soon, this is the last version before production.  But a drawing worht hours of talking :

[image: software cycle diagram]

Concerning red5 I have no clue what it is, but it cleary mean it's almost in a final state and almost stable.  RC2 is probably more stable and more recent **but according to the [Change Log](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/doc/trunk/changelog.txt) be careful because there is one RC1 and RC2 for both version `0.6.0` and `0.8.0`. So please read the change log to know precisely what's new in the version you're interested in.**

Source:
[Wikipedia Software life cycle management](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Software_dev2.svg/200px-Software_dev2.svg.png)

Comment: so I can assume RC2 is newer than RC1?

Comment: yes you can. Also the best way to know is probably to see the release note but I can't find them

Comment: That is a very helpful answer above with graphic layout! Thanks.